# Why my program not running?

Tags: android

Following is the program for ListFragment. It doesn't show any error but doesn't run. Error Log shows message `Fatal Exception:Main...` When I open on emulator it shows "Unfortunately listfragment2 has stopped".

Frament1.java code

```
package com.example.listfragmentexample2;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
    String[] presidents = {
            "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
            "John F. Kennedy",
            "Lyndon B. Johnson",
            "Richard Nixon",
            "Gerald Ford",
            "Jimmy Carter",
            "Ronald Reagan",
            "George H. W. Bush",
            "Bill Clinton",
            "George W. Bush",
            "Barack Obama"
    };
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, 
            int position, long id) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                "You have selected " + presidents[position], 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

activitymain.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment1.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Following is error logs:

```
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.listfragmentexample2/com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
03-05 17:51:24.935: E/AndroidRuntime(755):  ... 11 more
)
```

Comment: and format the code if possible :)

Comment: `It doesn't show any error` is in evident contrast with `Error Log shows message Fatal Exception:Main...` and `on emulator it shows "Unfortunately listfragment2 has stopped"`

Comment: @ArtooDetoo code format completed :)

Comment: @Artoo it doesn't show any error but it shows exception...

Comment: ... which is the very same thing, don't you? the program doesn't work due to some errors, therefore, it spits out an exception...

Comment: there is difference between error and exception!

Comment: @user3337747 post the stacktrace. extract the exception part from the logcat and add it to your question

Comment: exception part posted..thanku all for ur efforts to help me..

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.listfragmentexample2.MainActivity
```

Make sure the package and class names in your manifest file and code agree.

Manifest says there should be a class by name `com.example.listfragmentexample2.MainActivity` but it wasn't found in the binary package. If you're sure you have it there, clean and rebuild in case there was a build glitch earlier.

Updated answer to updated question:

```
com.example.listfragmentexample2.Fragment1 cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Your `Fragment1` is declared as an `activity` in manifest but it does not `extends Activity`. Only activities should be listed as activities in manifest. Fragments need an activity to host them.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Adapter after onCreateView method

```
        public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
     String[] presidents = {
      "Dwight D. Eisenhower",
     "John F. Kennedy",
       "Lyndon B. Johnson",
        "Richard Nixon",
       "Gerald Ford",
        "Jimmy Carter",
      "Ronald Reagan",
      "George H. W. Bush",
      "Bill Clinton",
      "George W. Bush",
      "Barack Obama"
         };
        @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
      ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));

        super.onStart();
    }
        @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          }

        public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, 
         int position, long id) 
          { 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
         "You have selected " + presidents[position], 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
            }
```

Comment: you were calling setAdater method inside onCreate where as this is a fragment so you need to call after or inside onCreateView. read Fragment life cycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in `onCreate()` method.